# How to combine logical gate NOT in lst.count((x, not y)) in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples, time-complexity, contingency

I am trying to construct contingency table from a list of tuples. The list looks like this:

`lst = [('a', 'bag'), ('a', 'bag'), ('a', 'bag'), ('a', 'cat'), ('a', 'pen'), ('that', 'house'), ('my', 'car'), ('that', 'bag'), ('this', 'bag')]`

Given a tuple, say `('a', 'bag')`, 4 things have to be worked out:

`a = lst.count(('a', 'bag'))` which is `3`.

`b` is the count of all tuples where `tuple[0] == 'a' and tuple[1] != 'bag'`, and it is 2: `('a', 'cat'), ('a', 'pen')`.

When I try

`lst.count(('a', not 'bag'))` I get `0`, although it should be `2`. `-----1`

`c` is the count of all the tuples where `tuple[0] != 'a' and tuple[1] == 'bag'`. In this case, `('that', 'bag'), ('this', 'bag')`. But when I try

`lst.count((not 'a', 'bag'))` I get `0`, although it should be `2`. `-----2`

`d` is the count of all the tuples where `tuple[0] !== 'a' and tuple[1] != 'bag` and it can be easily obtained from `len(lst) - a`.

My question:
Is there any way to combine logical gate `not` in `lst.count((x, not y))` or `lst.count((not x, y))`? If not, could you suggest to me how I can work out `b` and `c` without loops, because the complexity is `2(N*N)` which is quite expensive.

Your kind help is really appreciated!

Comment: Try evaluating `not 'bag'` in your interpreter. Any non-empty string will have a boolean value `True`, and so `not 'bag'` will be literal `False`. Thus you are counting `('a', False)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `not` in `count` in this way. If you do `lst.count(('a', not 'bag'))`, the `not 'bag'` is evaluated to `False` first, so you are effectively counting `('a', False)`.

Instead, you can use `sum` with a condition, comparing the first and second element of the tuples:

```
>>> lst = [('a', 'bag'), ('a', 'bag'), ('a', 'bag'), ('a', 'cat'), ('a', 'pen'), ('that', 'house'), ('my', 'car'), ('that', 'bag'), ('this', 'bag')]
>>> lst.count(('a', 'bag'))
3
>>> sum(1 for a,b in lst if a == 'a' and b == 'bag')
3
>>> sum(1 for a,b in lst if a == 'a' and b != 'bag')
2
>>> sum(1 for a,b in lst if a != 'a' and b == 'bag')
2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

lst = [('a', 'bag'), ('a', 'bag'), ('a', 'bag'), ('a', 'cat'), ('a', 'pen'), ('that', 'house'), ('my', 'car'), ('that', 'bag'), ('this', 'bag')]
# counting edges in 2 directed graphs
dct_a = defaultdict(Counter)
dct_b = defaultdict(Counter)

for a, b in lst:
    # dct_x[x][0] represents total count of occurrences of x in first position.
    dct_a[a][b] += 1
    dct_a[a][0] += 1

    dct_b[b][a] += 1
    dct_b[b][0] += 1

def compute_coocurrence(a, b):
    out = {}
    out['both_occur']  = dct_a[a][b]
    out['a_but_not_b'] = dct_a[a][0] - dct_a[a][b]
    out['b_but_not_a'] = dct_b[b][0] - dct_b[b][a]
    return out

print compute_coocurrence('a', 'bag')
```

Python `collections` provides 2 nice data structures that can help in your problem. This approach constructs 2 dicts that are indexed by first and second index in your tuple respectively. So `dct_a['a']` holds the counts of co-occurrences (with a) of all b's. I believe this suggests an O(n) two-pass algorithm.

`{'both_occur': 3, 'b_but_not_a': 2, 'a_but_not_b': 2}`

Answer (score 0):

you can define a function that in one pass count all 4 combinations like this

```
>>> def my_count(iterable,a,b):
        both    = 0
        a_not_b = 0
        not_a_b = 0
        neither = 0 
        for x,y in iterable:
            if x == a and y == b:
                both += 1
            if x == a and y!= b:
                a_not_b += 1
            if x != a and y == b:
                not_a_b += 1
            if x!= a and y!= b:
                neither += 1
        return both, a_not_b, not_a_b, neither

>>> lst = [('a', 'bag'), ('a', 'bag'), ('a', 'bag'), ('a', 'cat'), ('a', 'pen'), ('that', 'house'), ('my', 'car'), ('that', 'bag'), ('this', 'bag')]
>>> my_count(lst,"a","bag")
(3, 2, 2, 2)
>>>
```

and to make it more verbose, you can add a nametuple like this

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> CountTuple = namedtuple("CountTuple","both a_not_b not_a_b neither")
>>> def my_count(iterable,a,b):
        #same as before 
        ...
        return CountTuple(both,a_not_b,not_a_b,neither)

>>> result = my_count(lst,"a","bag")
>>> result
CountTuple(both=3, a_not_b=2, not_a_b=2, neither=2)
>>> result.both
3
>>> result.a_not_b
2
>>> result.not_a_b
2
>>> result.neither
2
>>>
```